# Representation that is semisimple passing to algebraic closure

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$, $k^a$ be an algebraic closure of $k$, $V$ be a finite dimensional $k$-representation of $G$. If the base change representation $V_{k^a}$ is  semisimple, then is $V$ semisimple?

For example, continuous real representations of compact groups are semisimple. It somehow leads me to ask the precedent question (since it is well-known that complex representations are semisimple, but of couse this conclusion is also direct for real case).

Answer (score 0):

**Fact**: Let $G$ be a group, $L/K$ be a field extension. If $V/K$ is a finite dimensional representation of $G$ such that $V_L$ is a semisimple $G$-representation, then $V$ is a semisimple $G$-representation.

The proof is taken from Bourbaki Algèbre Ch.8, Sec.7, no.4, Théorème 2.

**Proof**: For every $G$-subrepresentation $W\subset V$, $W_L$ is a $G$-subrepresentation of $V_L$. By semisimplicity of $V_L$, there is a $G$-equivariant projection $p:V_L\to W_L$. There is a $K$-linear map $h:L\to K$ with $h(1)=1$. Then $Id_W\otimes h:W\otimes_KL\to W\otimes_KK$ is $G$-equivariant and $K$-linear. The map $q:V\to W$ defined by $q(v)=(Id_W\otimes h)[p(v\otimes 1)]$ is a $G$-equivariant $K$-linear map. Therefore, $\ker(q)$ is a $G$-subrepresentation of $V$.
For every $w\in W$, $p(w\otimes 1)=w\otimes 1$ and $q(w)=w$. That is $q|_W=Id_W$, so $\ker(q)\oplus W=V$ as $G$-representation. This show that $V$ is semisimple.